# How to analyse multi-line log entries?

Tags: logging

I have similar log entries:

```
1. ACMEService|73312583[INFO|16/03/2012 12:39:03]: ********** Starting the operation **********
2. OtherService|73312584[INFO|16/03/2012 12:39:03]: Exception occured...
3. ACMEService|73312583[INFO|16/03/2012 12:39:04]: **** JAXB Objects ****
4. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
5. <ns9:local>
6.    <ns2:Header>
7.        <ns6:id>73312583</ns6:id>
8.....
9. OtherService|73312584[INFO|16/03/2012 12:39:03]: End processing
10. ACMEService|73312583[INFO|16/03/2012 12:39:03]: ********** End of the operation **********
```

ACMEService is the name of the service and the number 73312583 identifies a request. I want to display the log entries of the request number 73312583 of ACMEService (line 1, 3-8, 10).
I don't know how I could display them as there is a multi-line log entry as well (line 3 - 8). 
Is there a GUI tools for it? Or could I do it with the linux command grep? Could someone please give me an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[agrep](http://www.tgries.de/agrep/agrephlp.html) is a `grep` variant that searches multi-line records. I have used it too long back to remember how to use the `-d delimeter` option but it should work for you.

Using `sed` to join lines and `grepping` through those is another option. [This](http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/79965-multiple-line-search-using-grep.html) seems to do something similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would write a perl script to parse the logfile building a few associative arrays and printing the information I'm after. These scripts are one-off mostly.

You write your logfile in a multi-threaded environment, can you be sure that lines 3 to 8 are written consecutively? If not you need to adjust your logging to output a label which can be recognised by your parsing script on every logline.